# Can't create a postgres database with docker compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I can't create a postgres sql database using docker-compose.yml and an init file:
I'm using docker-compose to create my local database without success

What I have inside my docker-compose file is the following:

```yaml
version: '3'

services: 
    postgresql:
        image: postgres:alpine
        container_name: postgresql
        networks:
            - des-erp
        env_file:
            - ./postgresql/database.env
        ports:
            - 5444:5444
        volumes:
            - ./postgresql/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

So I'm using a init file as an entrypoint, this is what the sql file looks like:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE my_datbase;
```

The path is correct, and I'm using the command: **"docker-compose up -d"** in the folder the docker-compose.yml is placed.

It does create the container but can't run the init.sql file, the error I can see in the container once created is the following:

**psql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql: error: could not read from input file: Is a directory**.

My directory looks like the following, I'm in the "Backend" directory and this is what I can see:

```
ª   .gitlab-ci.yml
ª   docker-compose.yml
ª   README.md
+---postgresql\
        database.env
        init.sql
```

I do have the postgresql\init.sql file in the right place I believe
Im using Windows 11 btw
Any ideas?

Comment: Update: It does wrongly create a folder called "init.sql", that's why it can't execute it. I've added the  ":ro" option to tell that this is a read-only file without success.

Comment: If Docker is creating `init.sql` as a directory, it means that there is no file in your local directory named `./postgresql/init.sql`. Please update your question with the output of running `tree .` or `find * -type f` from the same directory that contains your `docker-compose.yaml`.

Answer (score 4):

in volumes section you specify path to dirs not path to files

change

```
volumes:
   ./postgresql/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

to

```
volumes:
   ./postgresql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

or to

```
volumes:
   <path to dir with init.sql>:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

where `<path to dir with init.sql>` is propper local path

Comment: I tried this one, It didn't work, it doesn't copy the file

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the following things to be double-checked.

```
ports:
    - 5444:5444
```

The default port number is 5432. Please confirm if 5444 is the correct port number.

```
CREATE DATABASE my_datbase;
```

Please confirm if the correct name for the database is my_dat**a**base.

Actually, the container I created on my local machine seems to be working well after confirming the above information.